# How to set up Factory Girl related configuration to be used by both RSpec and cucumber in Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-3.2, cucumber, factory-bot

How do I set up Factory Girl related configuration to be used by both RSpec and cucumber in Rails 3.2?

The configuration is something like

```
FactoryGirl.aliases = [
  [/([^(?:address)].+)_id/, '\1'],
  [/([^(?:address)].*)/, '\1_id'],
]
```

I tried putting it in `spec/support/factory_girl.rb`, and that worked fine if I'm running RSpec tests, but it doesn't get run if I'm running cucumber tests instead.

I'm considering putting it in `config/environments/test.rb` but it's not configuring Rails itself.

Answer (score 0):

Cucumber's setup isn't very well documented, but it loads a `features/support/env.rb` file first and then all other Ruby files in `features/support`. So you could add a `require` statement in `features/support/env.rb` to load `spec/support/factory_girl.rb`, or have a similar initialiser in `features/support`. And, given that it's shared code that sets up the test environment, I don't think it would be terrible to put it in `config/environments/test.rb` either.